# php empty() mistakenly thinks $_SESSION is not empty

Tags: php, session

In an online shop where the shopping cart is set in a `$_SESSION['shopping_cart'] array`, I have this check at the top of the page:

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
   //Not granting access for users with empty carts or when the session has expired
    header('Location: toanotherpage');
    exit;
}
```

This has all worked well until it didn't. For some reason a user that has spent too much time on the checkout page has gotten the session expired but it has somehow still slipped through the `empty()` check at the top of the page. This all happened after a form submission where the page gets reloaded. That meant that the user was charged, but further down the order confirmation and receipt could not be generated as the session was empty.

Can it happen that `empty()` somehow can mistake an expired session for not empty? Or can it theoretically be that the session gets destroyed while the script is executing so the session isn't empty when the check is done?

Thanks

Comment: Does anything further down the page affect that session value? It could be that `$_SESSION['shopping_cart']` *isn't* initially empty and that some later logic is emptying it.

Comment: @MichaelRushton it's only unset after order confirmation and receipt have been generated.

Comment: And you're sure it *was* empty? Remember that something like `$_SESSION['shopping_cart'] = array(NULL)` *isn't* empty.

Comment: @MichaelRushton but could it happen that `$_SESSION['shopping_cart']` turns into a null array when it expires/gets destroyed? Shouldn't `empty()` always catch an expired session? In this case I know the user has only stayed on the same page longer than the life of the session...and she had things in her cart.

Comment: Check to see what `session.gc_maxlifetime` is set to on your server and/or `php.ini` file. @NewInTheBusiness - See also https://support.serverlogistics.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=161 which may help, or Google "session timeout php"

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) || count($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])==0) {
```

instead of

```
 if (empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])) {
```

Comment: What can get past the original that can't get past your suggestion?

Comment: What happened is a rare exception, and like I said it has only happened once. What I would like to know is why this could have happened. I believe that the session was not regarded empty though it should have. Please read my questions at the end.